# Calling methods from multiple C files without custom header files, Makefile Linking

Tags: c, methods, compilation, prototype

This has gotten a bit lost in translation so I am going to be more precise:
we have classes recursion.c, fib.c, and countUp.c. from recursion.c we have to recursively call fib.c or countUp.c, decided by the input argument. I can't use header files and am only given that I must place prototypes:

```
int fib(int n);
```

and

```
void countUp(int n);
```

My Makefile

```
TAR = tar
COMPILER_FLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c99 -c
LINKER_FLAGS = -g -o
OBJS = recurse.o
C_FILES = recurse.c fib.c countUp.c
ASM_FILES = recurse.asm
TARGET_FILE = recurse
TARGET_TAR = PA5.tar

$(TARGET_TAR): $(TARGET_FILE)
    $(TAR) -cvf $(TARGET_TAR) $(C_FILES) $(ASM_FILES) $(TARGET_FILE) Makefi$

recurse.o: recurse.c
    $(C_COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(C_FILES)

$(TARGET_FILE): $(OBJS)
    $(LD_LINKER) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(TARGET_FILE) $(OBJS)
```

where fib and countUp class methods must be called recursively. The recursive.c file is considered our c driver. Do not create or implement any header files OTHER than those that are standard c headers (stdio.h, string.h, etc.). When I try to run this I get:

```
make
gcc -g -o recurse recurse.o
recurse.o: In function `main':
(file root location)/recurse.c:43: undefined reference to `fib'
(file root location)/recurse.c:46: undefined reference to `countUp'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [recurse] Error 1
```

Any clue what is going on.

Original Question:
I have multiple C files that I am combining into an executable. For example say I have math.c, the arguments are passed into it, and then if the input argument calls add it performs functions from add.c, if the argument calls subtract it will call functions from subtract.c, etc. The files are then compiled into a .o file, and then an executable is created. The issue I have is not being able to utilize header (.h) files. Is there any way to break into the separate classes or am I missing something? I really don't know exactly how to ask the question, jargon is pretty bad as far as C goes, sorry :(

I don't really get the idea of a driver I guess. (Not a device driver, she keeps telling us this is a c executable driver).

Comment: *The issue I have is not being able to utilize header (.h) files* - Why in the world would that be the case?  You can of course `#include` any type of file you like, but it may lead to name collisions and whatnot and is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? In that case, your teacher is probably trying to make you demonstrate your grip on 'extern' keywords.

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag homework, not looking for exact answers. We have to do it in our HW assignment without .h files that is where I am getting lost. We are practicing recursion and we have to call recursive .c files from our recursive.c main file. Also haven't worked with externs yet in class

Comment: The homework tag is in the process of being removed; you can specify that you're not looking for exact answers in your question.  Could you show us what code you're working with?  It doesn't seem right that you can't `#include`.  Compile with `gcc -E` (which does preprocessing but nothing else) and see if your headers are being pulled in.

Comment: Driver tag?  Are you being asked to compile this into a device driver?

Comment: This is too localized, it has no purpose in real applications and will not help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what I think you need to do is add the following prototypes above any of the functions you define in `recursion.c`.    The prototypes will allow you to call these functions from within any function inside `recursion.c`  (In fact, including a header file is akin to copy-pasting all of the prototypes defined in the file, as @Justin and @EdS already pointed out)

```
int fib(int n);
void countUp(int n);

int main() {
 ...
}
```

**Then you need to make sure that your project file includes the files recursion.c, fib.c, and countUp.c**  -  When you build your project, the linker will do its job and lookup the entry points in your compiled object files, and will proceed to assemble a single executable file.

What compiler are you using?

Comment: This seems more correct, but I guess my question is when I call the methods in the prototype, is it actually performing the method in the respective class? gcc

Comment: If by class you mean each source file (e.g fib.c and countUp.c) yes. The compilation phase in C works in two phases.  First the compiler will process each file in your project individually, top to bottom.  Whenever it finds a function during this process, it will register it's name, return type and parameters (this is called a signature), and so on, allowing this function to be called from another function You can't call a function if it's signature is unkwnown to the compiler. This imposes a strict ordering in the source dode where a function called by another function must preceede it.

Comment: This ordering is impractical, and this is where function prototypes kick in.  A prototype allows you to input a function signature, without actually specifying a function body.  So the process of including a header file is just giving the compiler a headstart on which functions may be called.  This removes the strict ordering requirement.   However, the compiler does not restrict you that a function being called must reside in the same source code.  This code might be in another .c file, or even in a precompiled library.

Comment: This is where the second phase, named "linking"  kicks in.  The linker will search all the signatures being used in your source code, and will attempt to match them against the entry points of the functions in your project (again, they can be in other source files or in libraries being included in your project).  If all the signatures found their corresponding matches,  the project will link and an executable will be produced,  otherwise the linker will inform you that it couldn't find a specific function implementation and will fail in producing an executable.

Comment: Hope my explanation hasn't confused.  Feel free to ask!

Comment: When I try to implement it like you said I get an error that I have an undefined reference. Why might this be?

Comment: Edited my question, error as well as more information is provided :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18607/discussion-between-sgorozco-and-zach-caudle)

Answer (score 1):

Including a header file is just a preprocessor directive to include the contents of that file at the location of the include. To achieve the same thing without a header file just copy and paste the code that you would have put in the header file into the top of each c file.

Of course this isn't very maintainable as if you want to change that contents you need to change it in many files, hence why header files exist in the first place.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified, can't use any sort of header implementation. All we are allowed to do is place prototype methods above our main function and then call our main function. I think I am going to have to go talk to her something seems really funky

Comment: @ZachCaudle Thats what I meant - in this case the only thing you would have needed to put in your header files are the prototypes

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework and considering the fact that you have told us that A) You have no header files to use, and B) you have not been instructed to utilize the `extern` keyword, it seems to me that your only choice is to include the .c files themselves:

```
#include "add.c"
#include "subtract.c"
/* etc... */

int main()
{
    // use functions defined in "add.c", "subtract.c", etc.
}
```

Note that this is bad form as you are including the implementation instead of the interface and likely pulling in a bunch of stuff you don't want or need.  If that doesn't answer your question then there is something, some instruction from your teacher, missing in the question.

Comment: You don't need the `extern` keyword to declare functions, just external variables.

Comment: @larsmans: Yes I know that, I'm just trying to cover all of my bases here as it's hard to figure out the reason behind this assignment.